# I have to make a new xml out of another xml. I still don't know how can I do it

Tags: php, xml

I have to make a new `xml` using the value from another `xml`. This is the `xml` code. I tried using `xpath`, but then I became confuse in order to display those value. Thanks for your help

```
<rss>
    <item id='1234'>
        <g:name>Gray</g:name>
        <g:description>It's a Bag</g:description>
        <g:detailed_images>
            <g:detailed_image>abcd</g:detailed_image>
            <g:detailed_image>abcde</g:detailed_image>
            <g:detailed_image>abcdef</g:detailed_image>
        </g:detailed_images>
    </item>
<rss>
```

The new `xml` format should be:

```
<rss>
<item>
<name></name>
<description></description>
<detailed_images>
  <detailed_image></detailed_image>
  <detailed_image></detailed_image>
</detailed_images>
</item>
</rss>
```

My bad, this is the `php` code that is still in progress. I haven't really figure it all yet. I'm still new to xml too. :D

```
<?php 
    $document = new DOMDocument;
    $document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;           
    $document->load('xml_edit_feeds.xml');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

    $xml = new DOMDocument;
    $rss = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('rss'));   

    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item) {
        //create tag item
        $createItem = $rss->appendChild($xml->createElement('item'));

        //getting item's attribute value
        $valueID = $item->getAttribute('id');

        //create attribute
        $itemAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('id');
        $itemAttribute->value = $valueID;
        $createItem->appendChild($itemAttribute);

        $result[] = [
            'g:name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(g:name)', $item),
            'g:description' => $xpath->evaluate('string(g:description)', $item),
            'g:detailed_images' => $xpath->evaluate('string(g:detailed_images)', $item)
          ];
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: "I tried using xpath" Could you show us that code? It would help us to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT?

Comment: Also, the initial XML blurb is broken since it doesn't contain namespace info.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I haven't, but I thought xslt is used for styling?

Comment: It's used to convert XML to XML.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ah, i see, I'll try using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot clearer using SimpleXML, but as you've started with DOM, I will stick with it and base the answer on that.

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->load('xml_edit_feeds.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$rss = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('rss'));

foreach ($xpath->query('//item') as $item) {
    //create tag item
    $createItem = $rss->appendChild($xml->createElement('item'));

    //getting item's attribute value
    $valueID = $item->getAttribute('id');

    //create attribute
    $itemAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('id');
    $itemAttribute->value = $valueID;
    $createItem->appendChild($itemAttribute);

    $description = $item->getElementsByTagName("description");
    $descriptionE = $xml->createElement("description", $description[0]->nodeValue );
    $createItem->appendChild($descriptionE);

    $dImages = $item->getElementsByTagName("detailed_image");
    $dImagesE = $xml->createElement("detailed_images");
    $createItem->appendChild($dImagesE);
    foreach ( $dImages as $image )  {
        $img = $xml->createElement("detailed_image", $image->nodeValue );
        $dImagesE->appendChild($img);

    }
}
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

It is a case of extracting each piece of data from the original document (here picking the elements out by getElementsByTagName) and then creating the equivalent node in the new document.

With the images, this has to use a loop to add each image in one at a time.

Comment: `@Nigel Ren` Yesterday I was looking for the answer to extract each piece in the foreach loop but I don't know how to do it. But I find an error that says 'Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array' in the `$dImagesE = $xml->createElement("detailed_images");`. Is there a way to solve it?